# Ctrl + Shift + Right not repeating

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just got me a Dell laptop with Windows 10 installed.

When selecting text in an application like notepad I am able to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Cursor</kbd> to highlight one character at a a time.

If I hold the <kbd>right cursor</kbd> down this behavior repeats and I am able to highlight loads of characters quickly without tapping away at the keyboard like I'm playing [Track and Field](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLeNExXflkc).

I then try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Cursor</kbd>, and I am able to select a whole word.  However if I hold down the cursor key it doesn't repeat.

The problem isn't just in Notepad, but all applications.

It's not down to scroll lock.

Comment: I assume it should, I will check later - I am currently on OSX where the Option+Shift+Right does autorepeat. Is it a problem for you to repeatedly press the Right key to add additional words to the selection or you just want to know why it does not autorepeat? If you need to select the whole line there is a shortcut for that too.

Comment: Thanks @Zina - It is a feature that I'm used to using a lot.  I'm a programmer and all day I'm working with text files (Fun!).  It definitely used to work in Windows 7.

Comment: Just tested it on Windows 10 - and it works. I tested in Chrome and in Notepad. So, do you have any software/utility which changes the keyboard behaviour? Can you check in your IDE settings if there is something? Try with another keyboard - just to make sure that it behaves the same way with any keyboard (physical, not layout).

Comment: @Zina - Really appreciate you taking the time to check your installation.  Unfortunately I've only got the laptop, and don't have access to another external keyboard.  It's not the IDE as the problem is common across all applications.  I've not installed any peculiar utility s/w that would change the keyboard. Very odd indeed!

Comment: You could check with a Live *NIX distro, or check with a Windows Install Disc (don't install it - just check in a text box), and I don't know if you have one or two CTRL keys - so maybe try with the second one. Maybe a friend of yours could lend you an external keyboard? And, for now I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Zina - It works with the right pair of Ctrl+Shift on the keyboard - I should have tried that before :)  It still doesn't work with any other combination of left + right keys, only RightCtrl+RighShift.  Bonkers.

Comment: I have only a left CTRL key :) - I am glad I could help.